# When does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n x_n}{n!}f(b_nx)$ converge for given $f\in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ and $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f\in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ be such that $f(x)=1$ for $x\in (-1,1)$. Given a real sequence $(a_n)$, define
>   $$ 
> g(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n x^n}{n!}f(b_nx), \quad x\in\Bbb{R}
> $$
>   where $(b_n)$ is another real sequence. 
>   When (i.e. for what $(b_n)$) is $g\in C_c^\infty(\Bbb{R})$?

---

If there are only finitely many nonzero terms in $(a_n)$, any $(b_n)$ would work. I don't see how one should approach the general case.

---

By the property of $f$, one has
$$
\left|\frac{a_nx^n}{n!}f(b_nx)\right|\leq \frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|^n\cdot n!}.
$$
Hence if $|b_n|^n\geq |a_n|$, then one has the uniform convergence. But still, I don't see how to get $g\in C^\infty$.

Comment: What does the subscript $c$ in $C_c^{\infty}(\Bbb{R})$ signify?

Comment: @Servaes: compactly supported,  I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I can put some constraints on the series:

1) If $inf |b_n| = 0$ then there can be only finitely many nonzero terms in $(a_n)$, otherwise $g$ does not have compact support.

2) If $b_n = B$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n x^n}{n!}$ must converge on the support of $f(Bx)$.

3) If $b_n \to \infty $ and $a_n = n! b_n^n$ then $\frac{a_n x^n}{n!}f(b_nx) =1 $ for $x = 1/b_n$ (and zero for $x=0$ ). I think the sum cannot converge to a $C^\infty $ function.